# quotient space of annulas identification with (x ,y ) going to (-x,-y)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying quotient topology . Basically I am trying to see quotient space geometrically .
I am trying to see a quotient space , I have a annulas and the quotient map is $ (x,y ) \rightarrow (-x , -y )$ . I am confused . Can you please help me to see it geometrically what should be the quotient space ?

Comment: have you done a similar thing for the disk yet?

Comment: @Andres ... when I take this map for a unit disk , I can see that if I break the disk as 4 quadrant then 3rd quadrant is identified with 1st quadrant and 4 th quadrant is identified with 2nd quadrant . So now resulting space is upper half of the disk where the line (0,0 ) to (0,1) is identified with the line (0,0) to (1,0) . I feel that now space is like a cone . If I am wrong please , help me .

Comment: oops i meant to say for the sphere or the circle.

Comment: try it for those two examples. Hint: they are $\mathbb RP^2$ and $S^1$ respectively by the same trick as long as you call $\mathbb RP^2$ as $D^2$ with the equivalence relation on the boundary that $(x,y) \simeq (-x,-y)$. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take the annulus to be $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 1/2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$.

Note that for every $(x,y)$ not on the $x$-axis there is another $(-x,-y)$ also not on the $x$-axis. Therefore you only need to consider the points above the $x$-axis which looks like a rainbow (or thickened semi-circle.) Now for all points not on the $x$ axis, each point in the quotient has a unique representative. What do you do with the remaining points on the $x$-axis?